# Add line to the head section of all pages on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, head

I would like to add a line to head section for all pages in MediaWiki.

e.g. to use Google Icons:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of the [hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks), get the OutputPage object and call it's [addHeadItem function](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classOutputPage.html#ad37dc926166096712154a6e2e3ca33d8). I don't recall the $name parameter making much difference, just $value.

Comment: If this solution worked for you please make sure to accept the answer